# Imgur API (rapidAPI) no longer works

Tags: imgur

Two days ago, something changed and the RapidAPI endpoint of the Imgur API just stopped working for uploads.

Also, it seems Imgur isn't responding over at the RapidAPI discussions, so hopefully their engineers see this. There's [a thread about it here](https://rapidapi.com/imgur/api/imgur-9/discussions/25519). I have no idea why Imgur does not have a contact point for their paying customers though.

My website has worked just fine and let me upload stuff with no problems, but it just returns a 404 error on the `https://imgur-apiv3.p.rapidapi.com/3/image` endpoint now. No other errors or messages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like many developers are getting this error. This can fix the issue

Add the `?client_id=<imgur_client_id>` query string parameter to API endpoint ​(POST /3/image).

However, you can always write to RapidAPI support team at support@rapidapi.ciom